# Implicit resolution working differently in REPL and normal compilation

Tags: shapeless, scala-2.11

I try to build a library to allow different representations of the same data structure with a minimal amount of boilerplate.

My idea is to describe the desired representation using a `shapeless.HList`, match it with the actual data structure, and then use it to produce the desired representation.

The first step is thus to verify that the type of the `HList` describing the representation somehow "align" with the type of the data structure to represent.

I'm not sure if shapeless provides such a functionality out of the box, so I've rolled out the naive `TypeAlignement` implementation below, using `shapeless.Generic`.

```
import shapeless._

object definition {


  case class Property[A](a: A)
  case class Embed[A](a: A)
  case class Hidden[A](a: A)

  def Prop[X] = Property[X] _
  def Emb[X] = Embed[X] _
  def Hid[X] = Hidden[X] _

  trait Representation[A] {
    type Repr <: HList
    val repr: Repr

  }

  object Representation {
    type Aux[A, R] = Representation[A]{ type Repr = R }
    def apply[A, R <: HList](genA: Generic[A], r: R)(implicit typeAlignment: TypeAlignment[genA.Repr, R]): Aux[A, R] = new Representation[A] {
      type Repr = R
      val repr = r
    }
  }


  case class TypeAlignment[A, B]()

  object TypeAlignment {

    implicit def hnilTypeAlign2: TypeAlignment[HNil, HNil] = new TypeAlignment[HNil, HNil]()

    implicit def propertyRightAlign[A]: TypeAlignment[A, A => Property[A]] = new TypeAlignment[A, A => Property[A]]()
    implicit def embedRightAlign[A]: TypeAlignment[A, A =>  Embed[A]] = new TypeAlignment[A, A => Embed[A]]()
    implicit def hiddenRightAlign[A]: TypeAlignment[A, A =>  Hidden[A]] = new TypeAlignment[A, A => Hidden[A]]()

    implicit def hlistTypeAlign[A, B, TA <: HList, TB <: HList](implicit headAlignment: TypeAlignment[A, B], tailAlignment: TypeAlignment[TA, TB]): TypeAlignment[A :: TA, B :: TB] = new TypeAlignment[A :: TA, B :: TB]()

  }
}

object demo {
  import definition._

  type ACL = String

  case class Address(city: String, street: String, zipcode: String)

  case class User(name: String, age: Option[Int], address: Address, acl : ACL)
  val userRepr = Prop[String] :: Prop[Option[Int]] :: Emb[Address] :: Hid[ACL] :: HNil
  val bogusRepr = Prop[String] :: Prop[Int] :: Emb[Address] :: Hid[ACL] :: HNil


/*
  def makeUserRepr(implicit gen: Generic[User]) = {
    val genUser = Generic[User]
    Representation(genUser, userRepr)
  }
*/

}
```

When I try that in the scala REPL, all seems to work correctly :

```
import shapeless._
import definition._
import demo._
user: demo.User = User(Homer Simpson,Some(42),Address(Springfield,Evergreen terrace,????),admin)
genUser: shapeless.Generic[demo.User]{type Repr = shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[Option[Int],shapeless.::[demo.Address,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]]]} = fresh$macro$5$1@85e91e7

scala> Representation(genUser, bogusRepr)
<console>:18: error: could not find implicit value for parameter typeAlignment: definition.TypeAlignment[genUser.Repr,shapeless.::[String => definition.Property[String],shapeless.::[Int => definition.Property[Int],shapeless.::[demo.Address => definition.Embed[demo.Address],shapeless.::[demo.ACL => definition.Hidden[demo.ACL],shapeless.HNil]]]]]
  Representation(genUser, bogusRepr)
  ^

scala> Representation(genUser, userRepr)
res1: definition.Representation.Aux[demo.User,shapeless.::[String => definition.Property[String],shapeless.::[Option[Int] => definition.Property[Option[Int]],shapeless.::[demo.Address => definition.Embed[demo.Address],shapeless.::[demo.ACL => definition.Hidden[demo.ACL],shapeless.HNil]]]]] = definition$Representation$$anon$1@72bc8c13
```

I get a satisfying compilation error when I try to match `User` with `bogusRepr`, and a `Representation` instance when I use a correct `userRepr` (and as a bonus, the nice feeling that I understand what's going on).

The problems begin when I try to un-comment the `makeUserRepr` function in`demo`. I get the following compilation error : `could not find implicit value for parameter typeAlignment: definition.TypeAlignment[genUser.Repr,shapeless.::[String => definition.Property[String],shapeless.::[Option[Int] => definition.Property[Option[Int]],shapeless.::[demo.Address => definition.Embed[demo.Address],shapeless.::[demo.ACL => definition.Hidden[demo.ACL],shapeless.HNil]]]]]` meaning that scalac fails to deduce a TypeAlignment in this context.

I fail to understand why this is. After all, the missing implicit here was correctly inferred back in the REPL session. Therefore I deduce that I don't really understand what's going on ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was silly. Those implicit will not come out from thin air so the above `makeRepresentation` method should have the required `TypeAlignment` via an implicit parameter, which may be tricky to express (since it depends on the `Generic[A].Repr`).

Looking further into shapeless, I've found out the ZipApply hlist operation which does exactly what I needed.

```
object definition {


  sealed trait Wrapper[+A]
  case class Property[+A](a: A) extends Wrapper[A]
  case class Embed[+A](a: A) extends Wrapper[A]
  case class Hidden[+A](a: A) extends Wrapper[A]

  def Prop[X] = Property[X] _
  def Emb[X] = Embed[X] _
  def Hid[X] = Hidden[X] _

  trait Representation {
    type Repr <: HList
    val repr: Repr

    def expand[A](a: A)(implicit generic: Generic[A]): generic.Repr = generic.to(a)

    def represent[L <: HList](a: L)(implicit zipApply: ZipApply[Repr, L]) = repr.zipApply(a)

  }


  object Representation {
    type Aux[R] = Representation{ type Repr = R }
    def apply[R <: HList](r: R): Aux[ R] = new Representation {
      type Repr = R
      val repr = r
    }
  }
}
```

I'd still like to merge `expand` and `represent` in a single function, but that would be for another question.